# Stack labels of varying fonts to the left (Tkinter)

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

**Code:**

GUI.py:

```
from Emotions_Switch_Pages import *
from Emotions_Root import Main
from Emotions_0_Menu import menuFrame

menuFrame()
frame1()

Main()
```

Emotions_0_Menu.py:

```
from Emotions_Switch_Pages import frame1
from Emotions_Switch_Pages import frame2
from Emotions_1_Main import raise_frame
from Emotions_Root import root
from Tkinter import *



def menuFrame():

    menu = Frame(root)
    menu.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

    w = Button(menu, text="Main", command=lambda: raise_frame(frame1()))
    w.pack(side=TOP)

    x = Button(menu, text="Add/Delete Emotions", command=lambda: raise_frame(frame2()))
    x.pack(side=TOP)

    y = Button(menu, text="Edit Emotions")
    y.pack(side=TOP)

    z = Button(menu, text="Detail View")
    z.pack(side=TOP)

    return menu
```

Emotions_1_Main.py:

```
from Tkinter import *
from Emotions_Root import root


f1 = Frame(root)
f1.grid(row=0, column=1)
Ti1 = Label(f1, text="\t Title\t  ", font=("Arial", 44))
Ti1.pack()

Header1_1= Label(f1, text = "Add Emotion", font=("Arial", 20))
Header1_1.pack(side = LEFT)

Content1_1 = Label(f1, text = "some text")
Content1_1.pack(side = LEFT)



def MainPage():
    Ti1.config(text="\t Title\t ")
    Ti1.config(font=("Arial", 44))
    Header1_1.config(text="Add Emotion", font = ("Arial", 20))
    Content1_1.config(text = "some text")

def raise_frame(frame):
    frame.tkraise()
```

**Question:**

I want the layout for Emotions_1_Main to look like this:

[image]

But currently it looks like this:
[image]

I understand the mistake I'm making but I don't know how to remedy it. My goal is to be able to center a title at the top, have a header line of font 20 below it, and then in a new line below that have some content. Do I need to use more labels? How can I change my code in Emotions_1_Main.py to make this happen?

Note there are other irrelevant pages of code I did not include here.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: This would be a much clearer question if the labels in the diagrams actually matched the names in the code...

Comment: Menu = MenuFrame
Title = Ti1
Ti_1 = Header1_1
C1_1 = Content1_1

Comment: using grid instead of pack would be much cleaner and easier but if you insist on using pack, you might need extra frames.

Comment: How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `side=LEFT` multiple times packs the widgets beside each other.

You want a normal pack(). Use an anchor to place the widget on the side of the screen.

```
Header1_1= Label(f1, text = "Add Emotion", font=("Arial", 20))
Header1_1.pack(anchor='w')

Content1_1 = Label(f1, text = "some text")
Content1_1.pack(anchor='w')
```

Comment: When I do that, the "m" in emotion mysteriously goes missing, and both the "add emotion" text and "some text" text are centered. How can I move them to the left?

Comment: Thank you so much!